# Should LDAPS certificate be imported into every client machine if it has to authenticate with Active Directory?

Tags: ssl, active-directory, ldap, ssl-certificate, communication

I am new to LDAP and SSL and AD. Trying to understand how to go about with it but could not find answers to some questions even after a lot of search on google.

When AD Certificate authority is installed it generates a certificate which has to be imported in the AD Domain Controller. Is this correct?
This import is a one time setting?

If there is a software on a client machine which wants to authenticate to AD, should the certificate be imported onto the client machine too?

Just setting the protocol to "SSL" in the software on the client machine is not helping. Should the certificate be imported into the certificate store in each client machine that has to talk to AD?

Answer (score 0):

The certificate shouldn't need to be imported on the client machine. If you are using a self-signed certificate, or a certificate from an internal CA, you need to make sure that the issuing chain for the certificate is ultimately trusted on the client machine.

You'll also want to make sure that the DC is listening on 636/3269.

You can use the `ldp` utility that is included in the RSAT tools to test this from a client.

Answer (score 0):

No, it should not be imported into every machine, however, the authoring authority (CA) should be installed in Trusted Root Certificate Authority on every machine that is using LDAPs. You AD certificate should be installed under the services side. Here is a script that will install your cert into the correct location. Once you're done installing I recommend using the LDP.exe utility to verify. This script will use a PFX certificate file. The script will copy it to local C drive on the root then delete it after you're done. You will need to update the following:

*The path can be **UNC** or **local***

$cert_name = "**FullNameOfCertPfx.pfx**"

$cert_path = "**PathNameHere**\$cert_name"

$pwd = "**Put your PFX Password here**"

```
$dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | sort name
for($i =0; $i -lt $dcs.Count; $i++)
{
    $cert_name = "**FullNameOfCertPfx.pfx**"
    $cert_path = "**PathNameHere**\$cert_name"
    $cert_dst = "\\" + $dcs[$i].name + "\c$\"

    #This will copy it to the DC
    Copy-Item -Path $cert_path -Destination $cert_dst -Force -Confirm: $false -Verbose

    Write-Verbose $dcs[$i].name -Verbose

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $dcs[$i].name -ScriptBlock {
        $pwd = "Put your PFX Password here"
        $cert_pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -AsPlainText -Force
        $cert = Import-PfxCertificate -Password $cert_pwd -FilePath "C:\star_corp-nutanix-with-key.pfx" cert:\localMachine\my -Verbose
        $reg_path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\MY\Certificates\$($cert.Thumbprint)"
        $reg_dst = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Services\NTDS\SystemCertificates\MY\Certificates\"
        if(!(Test-Path $reg_dst))
        {
            if(!(Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Services\NTDS"))
            {
                New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Services\" -Name "NTDS" -Verbose
            }
            if(!(Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Services\NTDS\SystemCertificates"))
            {
                New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Services\NTDS" -Name "SystemCertificates" -Verbose
            }
            if(!(Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Services\NTDS\SystemCertificates\My"))
            {
                New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Services\NTDS\SystemCertificates" -Name "My" -Verbose
            }
            if(!(Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Services\NTDS\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates"))
            {
                New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Services\NTDS\SystemCertificates\My" -Name "Certificates" -Verbose
            }
        }
        else{Write-Verbose "Path is there" -Verbose}
        Move-Item $reg_path $reg_dst -Verbose
        Remove-Item -Path "c:\$cert_name" -Verbose
    }
}
```